# IOIS / delphi: How to add a Key-value observing to AVPlayer.status (IE: addObserver)?

Tags: ios, delphi, avplayer, firemonkey

The IOS doc say we must add a KVO (Key-value observing) https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KVO.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH16 to the status field of the AVplayer to know when it's status change. However under delphi i don't understand how we can do this ? their is even no addObserver method on NSObject :(

exemple how it's done under objective-c :

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"player.currentItem.status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:AVPlayerItemStatusContext];
```

Comment: Someone got the question ban. Why don't you fix your existing questions. There is certainly value in them, but not the way you ask them. You are champion in asking horrible questions and you refuse to listen. I am not sure if you will be able to get answers to your questions here because you are doing things only few know how to do, but at least you would not get down voted and close voted. And maybe once in a while you may get the answer you seek.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar : i tried to update my previous question, but i can not because i m banned, so i can only create new. I agree that sometime my question are badly written (i m not fluent in english my fault), and because of this sometime i avoid too much of verbosity in the question making it not easy understandable for people that don't know already the problem. I will try to improve a little of this in futur

Comment: You are banned from asking questions, not from editing them. And English is not your problem. It is everything else...

Comment: no can't edit, only delete ... doesn't matter now i m not banned anymore :)